# Perl Usage error

Tags: perl

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this:

```
usage: gen-non-random.pl <count> <outputfile>
```

From the code below:
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w
    #
    # Script to generate non random values, to demonstrate a bad randomness graph
    # for my "Howto Analyse SessionIDs".
    #
    # written by:

```
$version = "0.0.4";
$filename = "gen-non-random.pl";
$usage = "usage: $filename <count> <outputfile>\n";

$count = $ARGV[0] or die ("$usage\n");
$output = $ARGV[1] or die ("$usage\n");
print ("-- $filename Version: $version\n");

use Time::HiRes qw( usleep ualarm gettimeofday tv_interval );
use Math::Random;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

open (OUT, ">$output") or die ("Can't open $output\n");

for ($i=0; $i<$count;$i++)
{
# generate a random number
$random = random_uniform();
# cut out char 3-9 of $random and put it in $randsub
$randsub = substr($random, 2, 6);
# get seconds and microseconds since epoch
($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday;
# get the last two chars of the seconds and put them into $s
$s = substr($seconds, 8, 2);
# sleep for a while
usleep $randsub;
# put together the last two digits of seconds and the microseconds
$time = $s . $microseconds;
$md5_time=md5_hex($time);
# print out the stuff we put together above
print OUT ("$md5_time\n");
}
close (OUT) or die ("Can't close $output\n");
print ("$count values written to $output\n");
exit;
```

I am new to programming so i need really simple answer please! I do not own this code I am using for my research paper at University. Also, could someone please explain to me what Usage actually is i can't seem to find a good explanation for it?
Thanks.

Comment: This is the exact same question you asked yesterday (although you seem to have since deleted it). Two people explained in comments why you were getting the error. What didn't you understand about their explanations?

Comment: And just for good measure: it means that the script expects two arguments, an integer count and an output file name. To run it, do something like: `gen-non-random.pl 10 output.txt`

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21443286/223226

Comment: Not _entirely_ sure it's kosher to mark a question as a dupe of one user has deleted. That rather defeats the purpose of the dupe mark since the vast majority of people can't even see the "original".

Comment: @paxdiablo perhaps, but also notice attention given to deleted question. btw, you can undelete it.

Comment: Repeats an identical question that has since been deleted.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the replies. I had to repeat the question because I didn't understand the answers i received. As a complete beginner to programming I didn't understand what I had to do to make it work and i am under a lot of pressure to get this done, so i thought repeating the question would allow me to understand it better. All I wanted was exactly what was posted in the answer section below,and it has helped me considerably. I apologise if reposting wasn't the correct way to do it but it worked, so thank you for you help.  @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you're not *using* the program correctly:

```
usage: gen-non-random.pl <count> <outputfile>
```

This basically means you have to provide a count and output file as arguments, such as:

```
perl gen-non-random.pl 42 outfile.txt
```

This will generate forty-two numbers and output them to the `outfile.txt` file.

It's the two lines near the start, checking `ARGV[0/1]` and `die`-ing if you don't provide them, that are outputting this message and exiting the program.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That makes sense, Ive run the code but i am not getting any output files, i assume this is due to the program automatically exiting as it says in the script? Thanks Again.

Comment: @user3250789, that's correct - `die` will output the string given to it, then exit.

Comment: Great thank you :) I have managed to get it working which is an amazing relief! @paxdiablo

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I can't run the above code because Time::HiRes::ualarm() is not implemented on Windows. That said, it appears to be generating a MD5 has string of the current time (in integer form) after sleeping for a random number of seconds, then dumping the result into a text file. You are getting the usage message mentioned above because the program expects input. Try running it from the command line like so:

```
perl gen-non-random.pl 10 MyResults.txt
```

I suspect that will dump 10 HD5 hash results into a file called "MyResults.txt".